# How do I make a PHP $row ahref?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I've search googl on how to achieve this but each suggestion doesn't work, either it doesn't display the results from the database or the "" characters appear above the table.

What I'm hoping to achieve here is to have the last row of this table display as a link as it's a shortened link that will be displayed in there.

```
    foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>
        <td id="card_name_text">'.$row["name"].'</td>
        <td id="card_type_text">'.$row["rarity"].'</td>
        <td id="card_foil_text">'.$row["serial"].'</td>
        <td id="card_rare_text">'.$row["link"].'</td> // This row
    </tr>';
}
```

These are the methods I've tried:

```
<ahref="<td id="card_rare_text">'.$row["link"].'</td>"></a>

<td id="card_rare_text"><a href="'.$row["link"].'"></a></td>

<td id="card_rare_text">'.$row["<a href="link"></a>"].'</td>

<td id="card_rare_text">'<a href=".$row["link"].'</td>"></a>
```

I'm not a PHP enthusiast so I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens with this one `<td id="card_rare_text"><a `? Put something before the closing `</a>` so you can click it.

Comment: I gave that a try but the results from the db no longer display

Comment: Can you update the question to show what you changed, and/or what it renders the page as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the **href** must point to an actual web address... you mentioned that `$row['link']` is a shortened URL, so you'll need to expand that in the href section to get it to work.

For example, if your shortened URL is "CNN", then the working line would be:

```
<td id="card_rare_text"><a href="http://www.'.$row["link"].'.com">$row["link"]</a></td>
```

The text between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags is whatever you want to display to the user to click on.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This is another great solution I'll be using, something so little too! I don;t have to use a value on my input field now, thank you again, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should finish the **a** tag before closing the **td**. also add something into the tag. In this example I've placed &nbsp which is just a safe empty space.

```
<td id="card_rare_text"><a href="<?php echo $row["link"];?>">&nbsp;</a></td>
```

Comment: Kinda difficult to click on a space character ;)

Comment: Also, `<?php echo...` won't work inside a string literal like OP is using

Comment: @Phil OP didn't brief, I suggested thinking maybe they have some CSS tricks under their sleeve.
for the string literal, You're right, but I've noticed lower resource usage when using as less PHP as possible, going in and out of PHP and meshing HTML, but that's for another story.

Comment: `<?php echo...` **will** work inside a string literal.  The string-literal thing where you put the variable within brackets is when you're inside **php**, and you want to put a variable inside quotes.

Comment: @FoulFoot it most certainly **will not**. I suggest you try it if you're not sure... `echo 'Here is my string with <?php echo $something ?> in it';`. This is what OP is currently using

Answer (score 0):

Please try it this way

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo "<table>";
    echo '<tr>
    <td id="card_name_text">'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td id="card_type_text">'.$row["rarity"].'</td>
    <td id="card_foil_text">'.$row["serial"].'</td>
    <td id="card_rare_text"><a href="'.$row["link"].'"> Link name</a></td>
    </tr>';
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Or even this way if the link has to know his name from the row.

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo "<table>";
    echo '<tr>
    <td id="card_name_text">'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td id="card_type_text">'.$row["rarity"].'</td>
    <td id="card_foil_text">'.$row["serial"].'</td>
    <td id="card_rare_text"><a href="'.$row["link"].'"> '.$row["link"].'</a></td>
    </tr>';
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have `<table>` in their loop so why does yours?

Comment: @Phil just thought it was a good idea to add it!! But it should works even without it!

Comment: Using the second method and removing the '; seemed to have made it appear as a clickable link, but it's looking for a link in the hosting directory which is not what I was hoping. The shortened links are google links @FedeCaceres I've left it live on the link above so you can see

Answer (score 0):

One more option for you. You can use string interpolation.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td id='card_name_text'>{$row['name']}</td>
    <td id='card_type_text'>{$row['rarity']}</td>
    <td id='card_foil_text'>{$row['serial']}</td>
    <td id='card_rare_text'><a href='{$row['link']}'>{$row['link']}</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: It would actually be better to not echo all the HTML in PHP but rather switch out of PHP and echo all the HTML and only echo the variables by themselves.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I agree wholeheartedly. The OP should truly seek to understand MVC patterns i.e. separation of controllers and view logic.